# Yahoo weather API 7 Day forecast in Android App

Tags: android, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

I am trying to display weather forecast with Yahoo Weather API in my Android App.

The below service gives me 7 Days weather forecast :

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1940345&d=7
```

But when I try to convert response as JSON format value with Yahoo API, it returns only 5 Days values.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid=1940345&d=7&format=json
```

Please suggest me what changes I need to make with the Yahoo API query to get 7 Days weather forecast correctly.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm doing it on iOS but the service call should be the same.

Comment: I want to use it for web application but stuck on same issue.